Как завершить выполнение одной функции из другой функции в питоне. Telebot
возникла следующая проблема.
Есть телеграм бот (на основе TeleBot), в котором присутствуют Inline кнопки. С помощью этих кнопок пользователь выбирает то действие, которое ему необходимо выполнить. После выбора действия бот просит ввести данные для его выполнения.
Помимо кнопок с "действиями", после их нажатия вылазит кнопка "Вернуться в главное меню", соответственно остальные кнопки пропадают.
Так вот кнопка "Вернуться в главное меню" работает исправно, но при этом, функция, которая начала уже выполняться при нажатии кнопки "действия" не прекращается.
То есть нажали кнопку "действие", потом передумали нажали "Вернуться в главное меню", выбрали кнопку "действие1", бот сначала обрабатывает незавершенную первую функцию (действие), а после переходит уже к выбранной функции (действие1).
Как мне сделать так, чтобы при вызове функции back (ниже привела фрагмент кода), завершались все раннее выполнявшиеся функции и возможно ли это сделать в рамках этого кода.
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'lab')
def laba(call):
    message = call.message
    get_pacient(message)

... 


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'back')
def back(call):
    message = call.message
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    message_id = message.message_id  
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Отправить работу в лабораторию", callback_data = 'lab')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Отправить работу во фрезерный центр", callback_data = 'frez')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Связаться с нами", callback_data = 'call')
    btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Узнать прайс", callback_data = 'price')
    btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Бланк Заказ-наряда", callback_data = 'blank')
    btn6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вызвать курьера", callback_data = 'drive')
    markup.add(btn6).row(btn2).row(btn1).row(btn4).row(btn5).row(btn3)
    bot.send_message(chat_id, text=" Вы вернулись в главное меню.\nВнимание❗\n\nВаши данные не были сохранены. При необходимости отправить нам работу,начните ввод данных с помощью кнопок заново.", reply_markup=markup)

    

#ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'text'])   
def get_pacient(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    back = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню", callback_data = 'back')
    markup.add(back)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = "Отправьте одним архивом:\nзаполненный Заказ-наряд\nсканы/фото/КТ\n\nАрхив назовите фамилией пациента \n\nВнимание! Все файлы должны быть внесены в один архив.".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)   
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_pacient1)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document', 'text'])   
def get_pacient1(message):
    global pacient
    pacient = message.text

    TO_CHAT_ID = 189414961 #DASHA
    TO_CHAT_ID1 = 6958017823 #ЯНА
    TO_CHAT_ID2 = 1242916181 #МАКСИМ
    TO_CHAT_ID3 = 5006586668 #PASHA
    TO_CHAT_ID4 = 1699523741 #SASHA
    bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID, text="ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ")
    #bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID1, text="ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ")
    #bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID2, text="ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ")
    #bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID3, text="ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ")
    #bot.send_message(TO_CHAT_ID4, text="ЛАБОРАТОРИЯ")
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    #bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID1, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    #bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID2, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    #bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID3, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    #bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID4, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Мы записали Ваши данные и скоро свяжемся для подверждения заказа!")
    start(message)



Если это что-то тяжёлое и долгое по времени я бы сделал так: при нажатии на "действие 2" улетает задача в отдельный поток/процесс/другую программу. Id юзера при этом ставить в очередь на "рассылку". При необходимости просто удаляете из этой очереди... Или самое тревиальное, создаете для каждого юзера новый поток/процесс и просто его грохаете если данные из него уже не актуальны

Не очень понятно. Удаление "ненужных" данных происходит вручную? Я начинающий программист, это первый опыт, поэтому прошу прощения, если вопрос глупый...

Почитайте про многопоточность для начала‍♀️ concurrent.futures; multiprocessing; threading; asyncio;
